# Debug whether a given config file actually ends up included?

Tags: nginx

I am looking for a way to quickly debug whether a given nginx conf file actually gets included directly or indirectly from main nginx.conf. Does nginx keep track of what config files it processes?

Solution **may** require openresty/lua and **must not** require Nginx+.

An ideal solution would add `X-Config-Read` header(s) to every response, and would only need to be set up in one place, without having to modify all `server` blocks, let alone all `location` blocks.

Comment: The `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) command will show you the entire configuration that Nginx will read the next time it's restarted.

Comment: @RichardSmith I had a similar thought and checked the command options (finding the same feature which is about all that's available). Config is read on startup and I doubt the source file information is stored. If the issue is purely to debug if a given file is being used, you should be able to identify this on Nginx startup. A simple option would be to add a config setting to the file you're testing (something benign that doesn't need to be inside a block), then grep `nginx -T` for that setting. Could be scripted fairly easily.

Comment: Somehow I've only just realised that `-T` outputs the name of the config file as part of the output already...

Comment: Welcome to the site panie Szczepanie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nginx -T` will show your configuration as it is read and parsed, including each time a configuration file is `include`d. The pathname of the file will be shown. If a file is included multiple times, it will be shown again, every time it is included.

Note that old versions of nginx do not have this feature; it was introduced in 1.9.2.